# Angular2 CLI Karma Unit Tests Failing

Tags: angular, typescript, karma-jasmine, angular-cli

I'm having issues getting karma tests to run for a component i'm testing with the Angular2 CLI. I have a component that uses elements setup in a module so figured it would be sensible way to structure the test (see below). In the TestBed config i am adding my module which also contains the component being tested to the imports array.

```
/* tslint:disable:no-unused-variable */

import { TestBed, async, ComponentFixture, ComponentFixtureAutoDetect } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MyBtnComponent } from './';
import { MyModule } from '../../my-module.module';

let fixture : ComponentFixture<MyBtnComponent>;
let btn  : MyBtnComponent;

describe('Component: MyBtn', () => {
    beforeEach(async(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            imports: [
                MyModule
            ]
        }).compileComponents();

        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(MyBtnComponent);
        btn = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    }));

    it('should create the button component', async(() => {
        expect(btn).toBeTruthy();
    }));

});
```

I get the following error when running the tests.

```
Chrome 55.0.2883 (Mac OS X 10.12.0) Component: MyBtn should create the button component FAILED
    Failed: Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'MyModule'
    Error: Unexpected value 'undefined' exported by the module 'MyModule'
        at SyntaxError.BaseError [as constructor] (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/0.bundle.js:29009:27) [ProxyZone]
        at new SyntaxError (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/0.bundle.js:4129:16) [ProxyZone]
        at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/0.bundle.js:11793:40 [ProxyZone]
        at Array.forEach (native) [ProxyZone]
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/0.bundle.js:11791:49) [ProxyZone]
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleSummary (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/0.bundle.js:11706:52) [ProxyZone]
        at http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/0.bundle.js:11777:72 [ProxyZone]
        at Array.forEach (native) [ProxyZone]
        at CompileMetadataResolver.getNgModuleMetadata (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/0.bundle.js:11764:49) [ProxyZone]
        at JitCompiler._loadModules (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/0.bundle.js:25082:64) [ProxyZone]
        at JitCompiler._compileModuleAndAllComponents (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/0.bundle.js:25061:52) [ProxyZone]
        at JitCompiler.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/0.bundle.js:25022:21) [ProxyZone]
        at TestingCompilerImpl.compileModuleAndAllComponentsAsync (http://localhost:9876/_karma_webpack_/0.bundle.js:28673:35) [ProxyZone]
        at TestBed.compileComponents (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:748:0 <- src/test.ts:3215:35) [ProxyZone]
    Expected undefined to be truthy.
        at webpack:///src/app/my-module/_components/btn/btn.spec.ts:41:20 <- src/test.ts:56909:21 [ProxyZone]
        at AsyncTestZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/async-test.js:49:0 <- src/test.ts:44340:39) [ProxyZone]
        at ProxyZoneSpec.onInvoke (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/proxy.js:76:0 <- src/test.ts:45032:39) [ProxyZone]
        at Zone.runGuarded (webpack:///~/zone.js/dist/zone.js:126:0 <- src/test.ts:65298:47) [ProxyZone => ProxyZone]
        at runInTestZone (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:105:0 <- src/test.ts:2572:29) [ProxyZone]
        at Object.<anonymous> (webpack:///~/@angular/core/bundles/core-testing.umd.js:48:0 <- src/test.ts:2515:17) [ProxyZone]
```

Below is my project config and the module that is being imported.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "my-project",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "lint": "tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update",
    "e2e": "protractor"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/core": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/forms": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/http": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^2.3.1",
    "@angular/router": "^3.3.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-alpha.15",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^2.3.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "angular-cli": "1.0.0-beta.24",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-alpha.5",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.0.2",
    "typescript": "~2.0.3"
  }
}
```

my-module.module.ts

```
import { NgModule, ModuleWithProviders } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { MyBtnComponent } from './_components/my-btn/my-btn.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        NgbModule.forRoot(),
        BrowserModule,
        CommonModule,
        FormsModule
    ],
    declarations: [
        MyBtnComponent
    ],
    exports: [
        MyBtnComponent
    ]
})
export class MyModule {
}
```

Comment: ...so where's the module? Please give a [mcve].

Comment: no need here for `ModuleWithProviders`. `Browsermodule` is also not needed because you have `CommonModule`

Comment: What is `NgbModule.forRoot(),`? You don't seem to import it anywhere.

Comment: NgbModule is the Bootstrap module. The MyBtnComponent uses elements of this.

Comment: I think what is happening is MyBtnComponent is not being imported by the module when running the karma tests. After logging this out in the terminal it shows this to be undefined.

Is there a better way for importing or is this more a config issue with the test setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this problem by restructuring my app. I think the main issue i was having is the karma-runner doesn't quite match up with the config of the compiler.

Comment: I'm seeing this problem too. Would you mind describing how you restructured your app?

Comment: what did you do?